# Vertical carrousel jquery or javascript continuous

Tags: jquery, jcarousel

i need a vertical carrousel to show some things like Lastest NEWS. And i need to be infinite and no mouse help... all automaticaly.
please i need inmediate help!, somebody knows where can i find something like that?

Thanks :)

REMAKE OF THE QUESTION:

i need something like the box: "recent orders" in http://www.dealextreme.com/ .... is in the bottom at the right.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [jCarousel](http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/). You'd combine the [vertical](http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/examples/static_vertical.html), [circular](http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/examples/static_circular.html), and [autoscrolling](http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/examples/static_auto.html) options.

---

Edit: [here's a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/37cc2/) to get you started.

#### HTML

```
<div id="mycarousel"> 
    <ul> 
        <li><h3>News Item 1</h3><a>Link 1</a></li>
        <li><h3>News Item 2</h3><a>Link 2</a></li>
        <li><h3>News Item 3</h3><a>Link 3</a></li>
        <li><h3>News Item 4</h3><a>Link 4</a></li>
        <li><h3>News Item 5</h3><a>Link 5</a></li>
    </ul> 
</div>
```

#### JavaScript

```
$(function() {
    $('#mycarousel').jcarousel({
        vertical: true,
        scroll: 1,
        auto: 2,
        wrap: 'circular'
    });
});
```

Comment: i need to hide one and show one time to time... Imagine a box with five lines like this: 
NEWS1
NEWS2
NEWS3
NEWS4
NEWS5

And i need that the line NEWS5 go to first and NEWS1 to last... and show the other like always... the Jcarousel shows like in pages, and is no good for me

Comment: Then you aren't looking for a carousel. It's really not clear what you want. Could you rephrase your question? A simple diagram might be helpful.

Comment: i remade the question... please reed

Comment: @Matt Ball This looks rather good, I will put this one in my toolbox. +1 to you!

Answer (score 0):

Look into http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/ which is highly configurable.

There is a vertical scrolling/sliding effect.

Specifically, you want some type of paging mechanism such as shown in the demo page:

http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/int2.html

jQuery Cycle is quite powerful but it does have a learning curve and you may have to experiment with the different easements to get what you need.

Also, it will scroll quite complex content in addition to images.

Comment: Specifically, look at the `fx: scrollUp` option and see the section called **Non-Image Content**

Comment: i remade the question... please reed

Comment: Based on your updated specifications, jQuery Cycle is not the solution since you need to view more than one item at a time. Matt Balls demo of jCarousel is a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

Following is vertical carousel, you can extract the code and use.

http://www.ajaxshake.com/demo/EN/890/920497f7/horizontal-and-vertical-jquery-content-carousel-jscarousel.html